# How to create a redistributable DLL that will work on other computers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to create a GUI that will try to interface with CAN peripherals connected to the computer and allow communication between the computer and a microcontroller. Most of the work is done in Java, but the CAN code is written in C++, and called from Java using JNI. I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 for the C++, and Eclipse for the Java.

The program works fine on the development computer, but I'm inexperienced with creating DLL's, and I can't get the program to run on another computer. I've used Dependency Walker to get an idea of what DLL's I should bundle with the application, and at this point I've included all the DLL's that it said were missing (there are a few it says are still missing, but it says these are missing on the development computer as well, and I believe this is just a problem with Dependency Walker).

The application folder contains a runnable jar file of the GUI, the DLL I created, and the dependent DLL's. I try to run the application from the command-line with "java -jar {application.jar}". I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\David\Dropbox\ATPBoardInterface\CANMessager7.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at model.CANController.<clinit>(CANController.java:34)
    at main.Main$1.run(Main.java:70)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Something that I can share with any other Windows computer that will be easy for the end user to install and run.

Edit: If it makes any difference, the program relies on the use of National Instruments' CAN software. I've included a number of DLL's in the application folder related to this which Dependency Walker listed, but I'm not sure if that's enough. Maybe the target computer will need certain National Instruments software already installed for it to work, and if it's missing, that may be causing the DLL initialisation failure? I'm not familiar enough in this kind of area to be sure either way though.

Edit 2: This is what I've bundled inside my application folder:

```
20/08/2013  10:56    <DIR>          .
20/08/2013  10:56    <DIR>          ..
20/08/2013  08:26           427,170 ATPBoardInterface.jar
20/08/2013  09:28           182,928 CANMessager.lib
20/08/2013  08:52           201,728 CANMessager7.dll
15/08/2013  16:28            30,720 CANMessagerXP.dll
16/06/2013  21:11           966,224 msvcr120.dll
11/07/2006  18:35           348,160 msvcr71.dll
13/10/2012  11:00           655,872 msvcr90.dll
01/06/2011  17:59            45,192 Nican.dll
06/04/2010  17:44            72,224 NicanCfq.dll
06/04/2010  17:44           125,472 nicanDBA.dll
01/06/2011  17:59           197,784 NIcanFrm.dll
01/06/2011  17:59            18,080 NIcanpu.dll
01/06/2011  17:59            61,568 NicanTsk.dll
26/01/2012  15:54            19,632 nipal32.dll
26/01/2012  16:11           309,920 nipalu.dll
26/01/2012  15:53            12,968 nipalut.dll
19/08/2013  16:18               772 README.txt
20/08/2013  08:34    <DIR>          res
20/08/2013  10:56                 0 temp.txt
20/08/2013  09:43         6,494,784 vcredist_x86.exe
              19 File(s)     10,171,198 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  416,406,867,968 bytes free
```

I'm not sure which of these are necessary.

Comment: have you tried writing a small native c++ program that loads the library?

Comment: Most people use a tool called an *installer* to handle dependencies. I recommend that you do the same. Also note that bundling the MSVC redistributable installer will not actually do any good, those DLLs have to be *installed* onto the user's machine. An installer can do that for you.

Comment: @Tobias Langner, I haven't, but would it be beneficial to try? I know that the code itself works because it runs fine when I call it from Java (with JNI) on the development machine.

Comment: @CodyGray I get that - if it's necessary, the end-user would be able to execute it and install the DLL's onto their system. I tried it with my target computer, but it didn't fix the problem. If I did use it, I could create a "setup" batch file which executes it and handles any other setup.

Comment: You cannot deploy msvcr90.dll like that.  It must be installed in the Windows side-by-side cache.  Use the Microsoft redist installer to get it there and delete it from your directory.  If you need more help then ask the owner of the DLL(s) you are using for the proper deployment instructions.

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be a 32-/64-bit problem.

If your CAN interface DLL is a 32 bit DLL and you are running 64 bit Java this will not work. Running 64 bit DLLs with 32 bit Java will not work either.

The only solution would be to compile the DLL as 32 and 64 bit version and deliver both DLL versions.

If the 32/64 bits is not the problem you could use the SysInternals ProcessExplorer tool to see all file access attempts. In this case you would see if Java tries to access any DLL file that is not present.

A solution for the 32-/64-bit problem would be the use of a command line EXE file instead of a DLL file. The data is transferred using the standard output and input (on the C++ side) and using the InputStream and OutputStream of the java.lang.Process class on the Java side. This will always work with a 32 bit EXE file.

Comment: I'm only using 32-bit Java. I'll try SysInternals ProcessExplorer, thanks.

Comment: I ran two versions of my GUI, one where it tries to load my DLL and one where it doesn't. I used Process Explorer to produce a list of DLL's loaded in each case, saved them to files and created a script to display only those DLL's that appear in the one case but not the other. I added all the DLL's from that list into my application directory that weren't in there already. Still no luck though. It doesn't complain about a missing DLL to be fair, it just says "DLL initialization routine failed". Is there a way to find out which DLL's have been loaded so far, and which it is trying to load now?